# gsettings-qt bug?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I have a problem using the gsettings-qt binding:
https://launchpad.net/gsettings-qt

Now I try to use it in my .qml

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import GSettings 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {
    id:window

 GSettings {
        id: test
        schema.id: "org.test.test" //I created this schema but it
doesn't work with any
        onChanged: changes.push([key, value]);
}
 color: test.testcolor
}
```

Whatever I do it says "unable to assign [undefined] to QColor, but if
I try to set the value like from a button test.testcolor = mycolor The
color gets properly set, but reading always returns undefined.
Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this won't work like you describe because GSettings has no concept of QColor. I assume you're storing the color as a "(yyyy)" (corresponding to rgba)? When reading that tuple, gsettings-qt doesn't know that this is supposed to be a QColor.

(Btw: you're getting [undefined] because gsettings-qt doesn't even handle tuples. I forget why, but maybe because QVariant is lacking a tuple type?)

Is this for an application? I think the SDK guys are working on a settings API that is a bit more friendly to Qt-types.